# How to enable Greasemonkey's "Find Updates" context menu

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

First Greasemonkey script I'm [writing](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/153869), so there may be something really simple that I'm missing. Googled around but just can't find it...

The metadata of my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Ordens de Batalha - MoD eBrasileiro
// @namespace       http://md-ebrasil.appspot.com/
// @description     Plugin para divulgação das ordens de batalha oficiais do eBrasil
// @include         http://www.erepublik.com/*
// @version         0.3.2
// @updateUrl       https://userscripts.org/scripts/source/153869.meta.js
// @downloadUrl     https://userscripts.org/scripts/source/153869.user.js
// @grant           GM_wait
// @grant           GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
```

According to the [documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40downloadURL), adding the `@updateUrl` and `@downloadUrl` tags should do the trick. But the "Find Updates" context menu in GM isn't enabled for the script (it is for others that I have installed):

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This may be a bug or poorly designed feature.  I can't get "Find Updates" to work at all; you said it does for some of your scripts?  List one of those, please.

Comment: @BrockAdams, for example this one works: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/131658

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first this looked like a bug, but it's not exactly.

The script in your question uses:

```
// @updateUrl       https ...
// @downloadUrl     https ...
```

It doesn't say it in [the documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block), but Greasemonkey directives are case-sensitive!

So, in order for those values to be recognized, you must use:

```
// @updateURL       https ...
// @downloadURL     https ...
```

When I corrected the case in your code, the ***Find Updates*** menu item became active.  You *may* need to uninstall the script, make the change, then reinstall.

---

To my mind, this is a poor design choice for Greasemonkey.  It certainly is an important documentation omission.  You can file [a feature request](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues) to have this case-sensitivity fixed.  Maybe the lead developer will agree it's a problem.